# Using echo in Bash with variable

Tags: bash, variables, echo

I want to use the line below to change a password. When I put actual values instead of variables, the command works perfectly.

```
echo -e "$sshpass\n$sshpass | (passwd --stdin root)"
```

`$sshpass` is a variable containing a password.

I tried the following to make commands work with no luck:

```
echo -e "/$sshpass\n/$sshpass | (passwd --stdin root)"
echo -e "$sshpass\n$sshpass | (passwd --stdin root)"
echo -e "'$sshpass'\n/'$sshpass' | (passwd --stdin root)"
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you sure the first one works when you use `echo -e "xyz\nxyz | (passwd --stdin root)"`?  It shouldn't change the password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not include the rest of the pipeline in the double quotes. The subshell (parentheses) is not needed.

```
echo -e "$sshpass\n$sshpass" | passwd --stdin root
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
echo -e "$sshpass\n$sshpass" | passwd --stdin root
```